# Issues with jQuery slice and double click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery script that will slice specific divs on my page.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-3 agg-item">
// code here
</div>
```

**jQuery script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".agg-item").slice(0, 12).show();
 jQuery(".load-more").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("div:hidden").slice(0, 24).show('fast');
    if(jQuery("div:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
        jQuery(".load-more").hide();
    }
 });
});
```

**Load more button**

`<a class="load-more">Load more</a>`

However, on my live site (works fine on local) I have two issues:

1. I have to click the button twice
2. The script only displays one new element on each click

Comment: Seeing your HTML (or a working demo) is required here. It will be impossible for anyone to help you given the lack of information you've provided